# Search and remove special character

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have below string in my DDL file and i want to remove the last `)` character.

DDL has the `)` character in many places, but I want to remove only in below place indicated.

```
..
`event_sts` string,
  `rsn_code` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ESCAPED BY '\\\\')                     <----- here
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
```

I tried using sed but somehow it's not working.

note: I have many DDLs with same requirement so the occurrence of '(' is not static.

Comment: `awk '/ESCAPED/ {sub(/\)$/,"")}1' file`

Comment: thanks for reply.but sorry. it didnt work.

Comment: @dileepvarma Do you want to remove `)` only if it is the last character on the last line in the file?  Or do you want to remove all `)` whenever they on a line that contains `ESCAPED`?  Or something else?  Please clarify.

Comment: i need whenever line contains ESCAPED only.

Comment: What didn't work? Use `gsub` if it is for every instance...

Comment: @jasonwryan Possibly,  the issue is that  `sub(/\)$/,"")` removes `)` only if it is the _last_ character on the line.  If the OP had a trailing blank on that line, that would be enough to interfere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove all `)` from any line that contains `ESCAPED`:

```
sed '/ESCAPED/s/)//g' filename
```

To change the file in-place:

```
sed -i.bak '/ESCAPED/s/)//g' filename
```

#### How it works

- `/ESCAPED/`

  This selects only those lines that contain `ESCAPED`.
- `s/)//g`

  For the selected lines, this removes all `)`.

  The substutute command typically looks like `s/old/new/` which looks for regular expression `old` and replaces it with `new`.  In our case `old` is `)` and `new` is an empty string.  Consequently `)` is removed.  The `g` at the end of the command tells sed to do this for every occurrence of `)` on the line, not just the first.